# How to break DRM protected files

Tags: windows-media-player, drm

Recently I downloaded a video file from a torrent site. I is protected with DRM. The file dowsn't even plays. When I opened the file WMP says ' getting media information...' and a window appears. It goes to the site of the torrent uploader. The option play from the window is greyed. Is there any other way to break DRM protection and make the files play.
ps: Already tried Almedia and Tunebite but they are of no use.

Comment: I dont think this is allowed here.

Comment: why it is not allowed ?

Comment: This is not a hackers/crackers website, and illegal. Read the FAQ.

Comment: Whether or not something is illegal is not for us to judge and depends on local laws. However, this isn't about breaking DRM for things you own, like making a copy of your bought DVD, this is a clear call for pirated movies, which we really can't encourage, sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no DRM protection. This is a lie. The file's sole purpose is to induce you to go to the web site and perform surveys, buy things, download malware, or whatever. It was a trick, you were fooled.

Comment: but there was no surveys. There was only a link to a software called gygan. thats all.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that you're missing is that Gygan [pays people](http://www.gygan.com/affiliateprogram/) to get other people to install their software. So this "video file" is actually an ad for Gygan.

Comment: the video file is more than 300 mb

Comment: Of course. Would you have downloaded it if it was 8K? And even if you had, would you bother to try to download Gygan to make it work if it didn't work immediately? This was a trick to get you invested in the file so you would download Gygan.